# Запятые после междометий

Tags: пунктуация

Всегда ли междометия выделяются запятыми. Как, например, быть в случае: "Ах(,) ты(,) негодяй!"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно Розенталю запятая в цельных сочетаниях "ах ты, эх вы" и т. д. не ставится. Так что в вашем случае запятые не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

нет не всегда,я бы написала так:"Ах ты негодяй!"

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **Ах ты, негодяй!**

"Ах ты" - целостное сочетание, запятая не нужна.
Но "негодяй" - обращение, никаким образом целостным с "ах ты" не являющееся.

Толковый словарь Ушакова:

НЕГО́ДНИК, негодника, муж. (разг. неод.). Человек недостойного поведения, повеса. ***Ах ты, негодник! что ты наделал?***
(Курсив мой, b-us.)